# Why am I getting raise UnknownValueError() speech_recognition.UnknownValueError?

Tags: python, regex, speech-recognition

I'm trying to write a script that uses SpeechRecognition to run a function once say a wake-up word "Run" Everything works perfectly up until I get to my regex search to find my wake-up word in my alpha variable that is assigned to what I say. Upon running I get the error. I have tested my regex alg outside of the SpeechRecognition with a string and it worked perfectly.

ERROR:

```
raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

Could I get some help?

CODE:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import re

def stt():
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    microphone = sr.Microphone()

    # check that recognizer and microphone arguments are appropriate type
    if not isinstance(recognizer, sr.Recognizer):
        raise TypeError("`recognizer` must be `Recognizer` instance")

    if not isinstance(microphone, sr.Microphone):
        raise TypeError("`microphone` must be `Microphone` instance")

    # listen and assign
    with microphone as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
    # return output
    return recognizer.recognize_google(audio)


while True:
    alpha = stt()
    print(alpha)
    if re.search('.+Run.+', alpha):
        print("1")
        beta = alpha.split()
        query = beta.pop()
        print("working")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your whole code under a try and except.

Like this:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import re

try:

    def stt():
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        microphone = sr.Microphone()

        # check that recognizer and microphone arguments are appropriate type
        if not isinstance(recognizer, sr.Recognizer):
            raise TypeError("`recognizer` must be `Recognizer` instance")

        if not isinstance(microphone, sr.Microphone):
            raise TypeError("`microphone` must be `Microphone` instance")

        # listen and assign
        with microphone as source:
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = recognizer.listen(source)
        # return output
        return recognizer.recognize_google(audio)


    while True:
        alpha = stt()
        print(alpha)
        if re.search('.+Run.+', alpha):
            print("1")
            beta = alpha.split()
            query = beta.pop()
            print("working")
    
except sr.UnknownValueError() as e:
    pass
```

If that doesn't work. Look at this [github issue](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/383)